# add to cart using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am thinking of creating a production ready e-commerce application. However I am stuck in add to cart functionality. For adding the product to the cart, the things required are product object and quantity, i think. I have created the serializer CartSerializer and CartItemSerializer and also the APIView part but I am confused which serializer to use or I have to make a different serializer which will have only field of product object and quantity to post. Because with my code, I am getting all the fields.

Here is my code

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Cycle, through='CartItem')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    tax_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, default=0.085)
    tax_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Cycle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    line_item_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart.id


serializers.py


class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'

    @staticmethod
    def get_product(obj):
        return obj.product.name


class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    item_title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = [
            "item",
            "item_title",
            "price",
            "product",
            "quantity",
            "line_item_total",
        ]


views.py 

class CartAPIView(CartTokenMixin, CartUpdateAPIMixin, APIView):
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    token_param = "token"
    cart = None

    def get_cart(self):
        data, cart_obj, response_status = self.get_cart_from_token()
        if cart_obj == None or not cart_obj.active:
            cart = Cart()
            cart.tax_percentage = 0.075
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                cart.user = self.request.user
            cart.save()
            data = {
                "cart_id": str(cart.id)
            }
            self.create_token(data)
            cart_obj = cart

        return cart_obj

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        cart = self.get_cart()
        self.cart = cart
        self.update_cart()
        # token = self.create_token(cart.id)
        items = CartItemSerializer(cart.cartitem_set.all(), many=True)
        cart.items.all()
        data = {
            "token": self.token,
            "cart": cart.id,
            "total": cart.total,
            "subtotal": cart.subtotal,
            "tax_total": cart.tax_total,
            "count": cart.items.count(),
            "items": items.data,
        }
        return Response(data)

    @staticmethod
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id', None)
        if product_id is not None:
            try:
                product_obj = Cycle.objects.get(id=product_id)
            except Cycle.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            cart_instance, created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
            if product_obj in cart_instance.items.all():
                cart_instance.items.remove(product_obj)
                added = False
            else:
                cart_instance.items.add(product_obj)
                added = True
            request.session['cart_items'] = cart_instance.items.count()
            data = {
                "added": added,
                "removed": not added,
                "cartItemCount": cart_instance.items.count()
            }
            return Response(data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Can anyone help me to connect serializers and apiview perfectly, please?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the conversation in the `Django` gitter channel. I simplify your code and here is my attempt to your question.

`carts/models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

from items.models import Item

User = get_user_model()


class Cart(models.Model):
    """Let Cart be a meta. And order_items is reverse relation"""
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    tax_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, default=0.085)
    tax_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    # Use ORM here to help you get the count() of each item
    # 1 item represent 1 qty
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

`items/models.py`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    """
    Represent the product in the system. Because I start the coding from `Cart`
    Therefore I put it as an `item`.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

`carts/serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from carts.models import Cart


class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.CurrentUserDefault()

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = [
            'created_by',
            'order_items',
            'subtotal',
            'tax_percentage',
            'tax_total',
            'total',
        ]
```

`carts/viewsets.py`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from carts.api.serializers import CartSerializer
from carts.models import Cart


class CartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
```

Since your model is `M2M` nested `order_items` is ready-made. And also `created_by` user is common. You can reuse `serializers.CurrentUserDefault()`
I used to read the answer mentions me that `get_user_model()` is safer because it returns an object. But `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` returns string. If you have no problem with that you can ignore. (Also correct me if I am wrong)

Let me know if my answer is inaccurate. I will try my best to redo it again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398341/how-to-update-user-data-if-if-user-data-already-exists-in-django-rest-api